# How to add DOCTYPE to HTML using XSLT and C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xhtml, doctype

I am using XSLT in conjunction with C# to transform my xml document into HTML. I need the DOCTYPE to be in the HTML document. But somehow I can't seem to get it to appear. Please help...

My xsl includes the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" indent="yes"/>
```

My C# code looks like this :

```
try
{
    XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(myPath);

    XslTransform myXslTrans = new XslTransform();

    myXslTrans.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XsltFilePath"] == null ? 
        "MyTransform.xsl" : 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XsltFilePath"]);

    String htmlFile = Path.Combine(myFolder, myName, "index.html");

    XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(htmlFile, null);

    myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);

    myWriter.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am using .NET 4.0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well don't write to an XmlTextWriter, simply use an overload that writes to a file e.g.

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XsltFilePath"] == null ? "MyTransform.xsl" : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XsltFilePath"]);

String resultFileName = Path.Combine(myFolder, myName, "index.html");

proc.Transform(myPath, resultFileName);
```

I used `XslCompiledTransform` instead of `XslTransform` as the latter is deprecated since .NET 2.0.

If you really want to use `XslTransform` then there is a similar `Transform` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6e130yd.aspx you can use.

Comment: The problem is indeed the XmlWriter which does not write the doctype. This simply works around it. Any idea why the xmlwriter does not output the doctype? That would *really* answer this question.

Comment: In my understanding the overloads of the Transform method allowing you to write to an XmlWriter are there to allow you to override the `xsl:output` instructions in the stylesheet. If you want to transform from an input file to a result file and want the `xsl:output` to control encoding, indentantion, doctype etc. then you should use an overloads that write to a file or file stream. If you really want to write to an XmlWriter but want the `xsl:output` settings to control the serialization options then use `XmlWriter.Create("result.html", proc.OutputSettings)` (for `XslCompiledTransform`).

Comment: That solved my problem and definitely helped me to understand the reason behind the behavior. Thanks a lot. Else I'll still be cracking my head here for days. Thanks thanks thanks.